# Maven TestNG Class No found exception

Tags: maven, class, testng

I'm running TestNG file from maven and I'm getting this exception.
I checked target folder of maven there are no classes generated

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test
>   (default-test) on project Tes ts: Execution default-test of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed:
>   There was an error in the forked process
>
> [ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException: [ERROR] Cannot find class in
>   classpath: ai.dharma.web.test.functional.TestBaseSetup [ERROR] at
>   org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81) [ERROR] at
>   org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)

Comment: testng.xml`code`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found answer almost after 5 days of deep search..

it was folder structure,it should be "Src > Main > Java" + your regular package structure, maven searches through that structure for generating class..